# Infinite loop error in Reactjs while using React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am new to React and trying to use React Hooks but I am getting error.
I am not able to figure out which line of code causing infinite loop as in the console it says

```
Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop    
The above error occurred in the <ProcessingInvoiceScreen> component:
        in ProcessingInvoiceScreen (at CreateInvoiceBySkid.js:49)
```

and from line 49 is the `const ProcessingInvoiceScreen = () => {`

```
import React, { Component,useState } from 'react';
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import * as actions from "../../../../actions";

class CreateInvoiceBySkid extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props)  
    }

    async componentDidMount(){
      if (!this.props.authenticated && (this.props.authenticated.role !== "superAdmin" || this.props.authenticated.role === "admin" || this.props.authenticated.role === "operator")) {
        this.props.history.push('/');
    } else {
      const user = this.props.authenticated;
      this.props.getProcessingInvoiceSkids(user);
      this.props.getProducts(user);
  }
  }

    render(){
    
      const ProcessingInvoiceScreen = () => {

       const [closedSkids, setclosedSkids] = useState({});
       const [selectedSkids, setSelectedSkids] = useState([]);
       if(this.props.processingInvoiceSkids){
         setclosedSkids(this.props.processingInvoiceSkids.rows);
       }
      
      console.log(this.props.processingInvoiceSkids);
   
        return(
          <div>
            Hello World
          </div>
        )
      }

        return(
            <div>             
         <ProcessingInvoiceScreen/> 
            </div>
        )
    }

}

const mapStateToProps=(state)=>{
    return {
        authenticated:state.authenticated,
        errorMessage: state.errorMessage,
        users: state.users,   
        processingInvoiceSkids: state.processingInvoiceSkids,
        products: state.products
    }
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps,actions)(CreateInvoiceBySkid);
```

What am I doing here that causes infinite loop?

Comment: Hooks & Class components are not designed to be mixed, either use a class component, or use hooks..

Comment: I recommend hooks **strongly**.

Comment: You are creating a component inside another component which may lead to unexpected behaviour. Try separating them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is causing the error. Every time the component is renderer, the setclosedSkids function is called and the component is re-renderer again and again :

```
   if(this.props.processingInvoiceSkids){
     setclosedSkids(this.props.processingInvoiceSkids.rows);
   }
```

Move this block to an useEffect callback function:

```
const ProcessingInvoiceScreen = ({processingInvoiceSkids}) => {
    const [closedSkids, setclosedSkids] = useState({});
    const [selectedSkids, setSelectedSkids] = useState([]);
    
    useEffect(()=> {
      if(processingInvoiceSkids){
         setclosedSkids(processingInvoiceSkids.rows);
      }
    }, [processingInvoiceSkids.rows])
    
                
    return(
         <div>
             Hello World
         </div>
    )
}
```

I recommend to move the function out of the parent component. Then in parent component:

```
    return(
        <div>             
          <ProcessingInvoiceScreen processingInvoiceSkid={this.processingInvoiceSkid}/> 
        </div>
    )
```